# Why vote is Nil class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Ok guys, these is my first attempt to code without any tutorials or examples, so may be I'm doing something terribly stupid.
I have a Rating modes, which parent to Party, which parent to Vote. I did't generated scaffold for vote, just model, as I suppose generally I don't need to have all standart controller or view here. I try to add simple voting system (I know about gems, but for the sake of practice wanna do it by myself)

So my Party model:

```
class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rating
  has_one :vote
  end

end
```

Vote model:

```
 class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :negative, :positive, :party_id
  belongs_to :party
  #def self.build(party_id)
    #return Vote.new(:party_id=>party_id)
  #end

end
```

Parties_controller:

```
def create
    @rating = current_rating
    @party = @rating.parties.build(:rating_id => @rating_id)
    #@vote = Vote.add_voting(@party.id)
    @vote = @party.Vote.build(:party_id=>@party.id)
```

commented part is one of tries to do pretty same thing.
And if in view I ask for class:

```
<%  @rating.parties.each do |item| %>
      <p><%= item.name %></p>
       <p><%= item.vote.class %></p>
    <% end %>
```

It shows 'nilClass'
Why?

Comment: First thing, you do not need to pass `:rating_id` to `@rating.parties.build`. So it should just be `@party = @rating.parties.build`. And next thing, it should be `@vote = @party.build_vote`. Try these changes and let us know what do you get.

Comment: Tried this all and still nil.

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is invalid:

```
@party.Vote.build(:party_id => @party.id)
```

Use this instead:

```
@vote = @party.build_vote
```

There is no need to assign `party_id`. The `build_vote` method does this for you.

See explanation on [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-build_association).

Answer (score 0):

```
@positive_votes = Vote.find_by_positive(params[:user_uid, :party_id])
```

find_by_positive expects to search the "positive" column in your db, but you are passing in a user_id and party_id.  Try this:

```
@positive_votes = Vote.find_by_user_uid_and_party_id(params[:user_uid], params[:party_id])
```

Comment: hmm, may be this is next error I will get, but now I realize that I even didn't create any votes, though try to assign them